# why is it not possible to view background-image in some sites

Tags: javascript, css, html, background-image

If you go to a site like this one [here](http://www.metrolyrics.com/tonight-lyrics-westlife.html) and try to view background-image with browser, it is not possible.

How is that made possible? I would like to implement that in my site. Give like a css or js script that makes that happen. Thanks.

EDIT:

please do not talk of this way:

```
#selector{
background : url('http://someurl.com') no-repeat;   
}
```

because I tried it and it does not do the trick.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend a technique or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow

Comment: I am asking for the way to do it because I have already tried it in the way I know backgrounds are added and it does not work.

Comment: *"How is that made possible? "* ...IS asking for a techique you could have found by a simple google search or **actually looking at the sites code**.

Comment: well, I have looked for an answer for more that three hours to no avail. So I resolved to stack overflow. I looked at the sites code and I was looking at the line for background. So I just did not know where to look. I am working on a project that requires that particular characteristic. May be I did not ask the 'right way' questions should be asked in stack overflow. So I do not think its off topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, the background image is not a CSS background, it's just an image setted to expand the whole page and sent to the background with a z-index.

**HTML of the image:**

```
<div id="bg-top" class="bg-top">
  <div>
    <img src="http://netstorage.metrolyrics.com/artists/hero/default/9.jpg" alt="Westlife lyrics">
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS to expand the image and send it to the background:**

```
.bg-top {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 584px;
    background: #000;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: -2; // This is the key, it makes it to be at the background
}
```